# grep on unix / linux: how to replace or capture text?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, grep

So I'm pretty good with regular expressions, but I'm having some trouble with them on unix. Here are two things I'd love to know how to do:

1) **Replace all text except letters, numbers, and underscore**

In PHP I'd do this: (works great)

```
preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9_]#','',$text).
```

In bash I tried this (with limited success); seems like it dosen't allow you to use the full set of regex:

```
text="my #1 example!"
${text/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/'')
```

I tried it with sed but it still seems to have problems with the full regex set:

```
echo "my #1 example!" | sed s/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_]//
```

I'm sure there is a way to do it with grep, too, but it was breaking it into multiple lines when i tried:

```
echo abc\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(222 | grep -Eos '[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+'
```

And finally I also tried using **expr** but it seemed like that had *really* limited support for extended regex...

---

2) **Capture (multiple) parts of text**

In PHP I could just do something like this:

```
preg_match('#(word1).*(word2)#',$text,$matches);
```

I'm not sure how that would be possible in *nix...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Part 1**

You are almost there with the `sed` just add the `g` modifier so that the replacement happen globally, without the `g`, replacement will happen just once.

```
$ echo "my #1 example!" | sed s/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_]//g
my1example
$
```

You did the same mistake with your bash pattern replacement too: not making replacements globally:

```
$ text="my #1 example!"

# non-global replacement. Only the space is delete.
$ echo ${text/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/''}
my#1 example!

# global replacement by adding an additional / 
$ echo ${text//[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/''}
my1example
```

**Part 2**

Capturing works the same in `sed` as it did in PHP's regex: enclosing the pattern in parenthesis triggers capturing:

```
# swap foo and bar's number using capturing and back reference.
$ echo 'foo1 bar2' | sed -r 's/foo([0-9]+) bar([0-9]+)/foo\2 bar\1/'
foo2 bar1
$
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to codaddict's nice answer using `sed`, you could also use `tr` for the first part of your question.

```
echo "my #1 _ example!" | tr -d -C '[[:alnum:]_]'
```

I've also made use of the `[:alnum:]` character class, just to show another option.

Comment: Note, the `:macro:` features in `tr` aren't consistent across implementations, and may be missing altogether. For instance, busybox's `tr` lacks them altogether (or did, the last time I checked)

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean you can't use the regex syntax for bash?

```
$ text="my #1 example!"
$ echo ${text//[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/}
my1example
```

you have to use `//` for more than 1 replacement.

for your 2nd question, with bash 3.2++

```
$ [[ $text =~ "(my).*(example)" ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
my
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
example
```